# ROR: Problematic Private Method in Polymorphic Voting Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am attempting to create an app with a SO/reddit-like voting structure.  I have the voting working for my `jokes` model and am trying to implement it for my `recipes` model as well.

So far I have this as my `erb` for the voting on `recipes`:

```
    <div class="text-center col-xs-1">
      <% if current_user %>
        <div class="width: 100%"><%= link_to " ", recipe_up_vote_path(recipe), class: 'upvote glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up', method: :post, style: "margin-right: 0; margin-left: 0" %></div>
        <div class="width: 100%"><h3 style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"><strong><%= recipe.rankpoints %></strong></h3></div>
        <div class="width: 100%"><%= link_to " ", recipe_down_vote_path(recipe), class: 'downvote glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down', method: :post, style: "margin-right: 0; margin-left: 0" %></div>
      <% else %>
        <div class="width: 100%"><%= link_to " ", new_user_session_path, class: 'upvote glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up', method: :post, style: "margin-right: 0; margin-left: 0" %></div>
        <div class="width: 100%"><h3 style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"><strong><%= recipe.rankpoints %></strong></h3></div>
        <div class="width: 100%"><%= link_to " ", new_user_session_path, class: 'downvote glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down', method: :post, style: "margin-right: 0; margin-left: 0" %></div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
```

This is my `votes_controller`:

```
class VotesController < ApplicationController

  def up_vote
    update_vote(1)
    redirect_to :back
  end

  def down_vote
    update_vote(-1)
    redirect_to :back
  end

  private
  def update_vote(new_value)
  #  @joke = Joke.find(params[:joke_id])  <<<<DELETED THIS LINE
    user = current_user
    if @joke.user.votes == nil
      @vote = current_user.votes.create(value: new_value, voteable: @thing)
      if @vote
        @vote.update_attribute(:value, new_value)
      else
        @vote = current_user.votes.create(value: new_value, voteable: @thing)
      end
    else
      flash[:notice] = "C'mon man, you know you only get one vote."
    end
  end
end
```

Where I am having trouble is the `private` `update_vote` method in the `votes_controller`.  Obviously, it throws up an error when I try to vote on a `recipe`, because it is configured for the `jokes` model.  If I change it to correspond with `recipe` voting, the joke will then throw up an error.  How do I configure this for the polymorphic nature of `votes`?

**UPDATE**
I updated the private method so that it has `@thing` instead of `@joke` or `@recipe`, and then I define `@thing = @joke` or `@thing = @recipe` in the appropriate method of the appropriate controller.  This change eliminated the error that was being thrown up, but the value for `rankpoints` does not change from `0` when a vote is cast.

Comment: You pass the model into a method that only knows about the polymorphic aspects of it. The only thing the controller needs to do specifically is figure out which model to retrieve.

Comment: @DaveNewton, sorry to be obtuse, but how is that done?

Comment: Write a method with everything but the find in it. Call it with your model.

Comment: @DaveNewton I tried to follow your advice and updated the info in the OP accordingly.  No error now, but the value for `rankpoints` does not update. Help?

Comment: I still see a reference to `@joke`. The method should not be in a controller; you should be *passing* the model to a utility method. No idea what `rankpoints` is or where it comes from.

Comment: Could you post the error and stack trace